# How to instantiate java socket given the interface name

Tags: sockets, binding, interface, local

There is a server machine and the client is routed to the server using two routes. 
Using `netstat -r`, I have both of the interface names. How do I create a Socket object using these names?

I know the Socket constructor has localAddr 3rd argument, but how to find it for a given interface name?

Note: `netstat -r` will print the interface names in the last column.

```
Socket(InetAddress serverAddr,
       int port,
       InetAddress localAddr,
       int localPort)
       throws IOException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can define hostname for each interface (`/etc/hosts`).
This way you could construct the `InetAddress` speficying the hostname chosen.